Question about my phone number changing without being manually entered
I am an end user and twice my phone number has been changed (and is displayed incorrectly to clients on company generated marketing). Our tech support says that a person did not change it (it's only done by admins at my company, no user option to change). They are saying that a SalesForce bot may have changed it. Is this a possible explanation? I've never heard of a program that goes rogue on its own and searches the internet for alternate people in the same industry to populate phone numbers. Can you help answer this question?

You're correct in that it's not really a thing that Salesforce would go into different organizations to update phone numbers. It sounds like you got a general IT support person telling you this "bot" is out there changing things. I would try to find out who one of the admins are and ask them directly. There are integrations and automations that they can setup that could pull your phone number from some employee database or active directory. But only they, the ones who actually set it up and manage it would know for sure.

Thank you, Dan!
